# WordPress shortcode not working properly

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

At first I thought that the button code itself is wrong, but it works correctly on Codepen. See the differences:

CodePen http://codepen.io/Bogette/pen/QxdJgP

WP http://testnewbogetterihtnow.000webhostapp.com

In Wordpress, the button has a jerky hover animation. Also on hover does not change the color of the text, although it is spelled out.

Your help is needed. The reason? Did I misspell the shortcode?

SHORTCODE:

```
    function text_button() {
return '
<style type="text/css">
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease, background-color 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease, background-color 500ms ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #fff);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  color: #000;
}
</style>

<html>
<title>Spectacular Project</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"name="viewport"/>
<meta content="Bogette" name="button"/>
<link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ad2f0250e93f375ebdb98dc/css/bogdans-spectacular-project-1a670d.webflow.f1a16b2d4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">WebFont.load({  google: {    families: ["Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700"]  }});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">!function(o,c){var n=c.documentElement,t=" w-mod-";n.className+=t+"js",("ontouchstart"in o||o.DocumentTouch&&c instanceof DocumentTouch)&&(n.className+=t+"touch")}(window,document);
</script>
<link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <a href="#" class="button w-button">Button Text</a>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
';
}
add_shortcode('tb', 'text_button');
```

Comment: You did a complete mess, just pasted the full html code in shortcode output. Please check How to include js and css in wordpress and how to write shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add everything starting from HTML body tag, CSS, scripts tag etc to the function of the shortcode.

Rather divide them and place it into there respective segments like

For example: Put the CSS into style.css under your theme folder. And add scripts to the header/footer as needed or enqueue within the function.php file.

Ref link for script enqueue: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

And to get the shortcode work properly just add this code to your function.php file under your theme folder.

```
function text_button() {
   return '<a href="#" class="button w-button">Button Text</a>';
}
add_shortcode('tb', 'text_button');
```

Then use the shortcode as suggested by Sarbaz in his answer

Please use following code for template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tb]'); ?>
```

You can use the code in your back-end text editors:

```
[tb]
```

And about the color of the text which you wants to be changed on hover effect. For that, there is no color mentioned for text in

```
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease, background-color 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease, background-color 500ms ease;
}
```

and under

```
.button:hover {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #fff);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  transform: translate(0px, -10px);
  color: #000;
}
```

i.e. **color: #000;** is given text color as black which is a default color for text under your theme and that is white in case of codepen.io. For that reason you can see the change in codepen.io but not under your theme.

So you may try changing it to any other color code like **color: #ff0000;** to see the impact.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code, its working...

Please use following code for template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tb]'); ?>
```

You can use below code in your back-end text editors:

```
[tb]
```

Please check the link for more: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/